# How to properly use style function when adding multiple Geojson leaflets to one map using Folium?

Tags: python, pandas, geojson, folium

I'm trying to add multiple Geojson leaflets of boroughs on a city Folium map, painting them according to the population density and can't get my head around the proper usage of style_function here

My piece of code:

```
colorscale=branca.colormap.linear.YlGnBu_09.scale(vmin=df_BoroughsSP.Density.min(),vmax=df_BoroughsSP.Density.max())

def style_function(feature):
    density = df_BoroughsSP.Density[i]
    return {
        'fillOpacity': 0.5,
        'weight': 0.5,
        'fillColor': colorscale(density)
    }

map_SP = folium.Map(location=[latitudeSP, longitudeSP], zoom_start=10)

for i in range(len(df_BoroughsSP.Density)):
 jsonurl='http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_geojson.py?id='+str(df_BoroughsSP.RelationID[i])+'&params=0'
 with urllib.request.urlopen(jsonurl) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
 folium.GeoJson(
    data,
    name='geojson',
    style_function=style_function
 ).add_to(map_SP)

map_SP
```

I get the  `dict' object is not callable` output. 
I tried using the list of precalculated values instead of style_function, but got the same result.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

I know it would be easier to use Cloropleth, but I don't have the Geojson file of the entire city broken into boroughs

p.s. I'm new to the programming, so any kind of advice will be very helpfull

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who will stuck with similar problem - I found that creating a composite Geojson and then using a Chloropleth method to display it is much easier, than trying to apply separate patches on a map with a loop

My final code:

```
# df_BoroughsSP is a Pandas dataframe with density and OpenStreetMap RelationID of each city borough


# Preparing a composite Geojson file from files of individual boroughs
features = []

for index in range(len(df_BoroughsSP.index)):
 jsonurl='http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_geojson.py?id='+str(df_BoroughsSP.RelationID[index])+'&params=0'
 with urllib.request.urlopen(jsonurl) as url:
    Geometry=json.loads(url.read().decode())
    features.append(Feature(geometry=Geometry, properties={"name": df_BoroughsSP.Borough[index],"density":df_BoroughsSP.Density[index]}))

feature_collection = FeatureCollection(features)
with open('myfile.geojson', 'w') as f:
   dump(feature_collection, f)
with open('myfile.geojson', 'r') as f:    
   GeodataSP=json.load(f) #Geojson file with city boundaries, broken down to individual boroughs
```